# Java - вызов метода с данными через некоторое время

Tags: java, многопоточность, таймер

Мне нужно вызвать метод отдельным потоком через 10 секунд, также, этот метод берет на вход данные. Например: `sum(int a, int b)`

`int a, int b` - данные на вход к методу `sum`.

Comment: Через 10 секунд после чего? Какое отношение к этому имеют данные?

Comment: Просто через 10 секунд, но я вызываю метод, к примеру, sum(int a, int b), где int a , int b это данные из первого метода

Comment: вам нужен ScheduledExecutorService

Comment: Что значит "просто через 10 секунд"? Что является началом отсчета? Сделайте sleep().

Comment: А не могли бы Вы, пожалуйста, показать на конкретном примере?

Comment: Надо сделать без sleep, отдельным потоком)

Comment: Вы можете копать в сторону Timer, он принимает на вход объект реализующий Runnable, и время через которое запустить этот поток

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы это можете сделать через JavaSE:

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

    private int a;
    private int b;

    public MyRunnable(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(a+b);
    }
}

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        executorService.schedule(new MyRunnable(1, 2), 5 , TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

}
```

Так же можно это сделать с помощью @Scheduled в Spring.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое)